# How to delete Managed package tab?

Tags: managed-package

As per spring 14 release note a tab or field added in a managed package can be deleted. But I am not able to find the delete option for this.  Anybody know this?  In winter 14 the feature was pilot but in spring 14 it is  not mentioned as pilot. Any clues please?
 [Spring 14 release note](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_isvforce_managed_component_deletion.htm)

Comment: I am not seeing an option to delete a field as well in a managed package, I checked and it is not referenced in another artifact.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to request the delete option to be enabled. I had a package from 2009, and wanted to delete some fields - but the option wasn't auto-enabled in my org after Spring 14. But I raised a case, and they quickly enabled it.

Answer (score 0):

Per that same release note:

> This feature is currently available through a pilot program. For information on enabling it for your organization, please contact salesforce.com.

So, yes, you need to contact SFDC Support to get it enabled in your ISV Edition org.

Comment: Spring 14 does not say it is a pilot program and my org is spring 14

Comment: Yep, this is now GA.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett  if it is not pilot, still I am not able to get the delete option for a tab. Should I unistall the packages installed for that particular version?

Comment: It can only be done once the tab has been removed from the package by the original package developer and you have installed a new version, is my understanding.

Comment: Yes I understand. I am the developer working on packaging org and I am not able to delete the tab included in relesed package. Documents say this can be done from developer side. Even though the org is spring 14 i am not getting option to delete the tab